# Reason for segmentation fault despite using equivalent statements

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, segmentation-fault, c++14

I wrote a function for implementing merge sort on singly linked list, where every element has an integer and a next pointer.
One of the function splitlist is used to split the given linked list into two linked lists

```
void splitList(struct node* source, struct node** frontRef, struct node** backRef)
{
    struct node *s, *f;
    s = source;
    f = s->next;
    while(f && f->next)
    {
        s = s->next;
        f = f->next->next;
    }
    *frontRef = source;
    f = s->next;
    s->next = NULL;
    *backRef = f;
}
```

Here source is a pointer to given linked list and frontRef and backRef are references to pointer which need to be assigned through this function. fronRef should refer to first linked list and backreef should refer to second one.
This code gives segmentation fault when the lines

> *frontRef = source;
>   *backRef = f;

are replaced by

> frontRef = &source;
>   backRef = &f;

I fail to understand the reason for this as both set of statements are equivalent to each other

Comment: @user200783 how is that relevant?

Comment: `source` and `f` are local variables, keeping a reference to them is not going to work well

Comment: 'Both statements are equivalent'. Clearly they are not. When working with pointers you must keep in mind the difference between copying the pointer and copying what is being pointed at.

Comment: @user200783 That was a part of some debugging statements that I removed before posting. I removed it now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
*frontRef = source; *backreef = f;
```

and

```
frontRef = &source; backreef = &f;
```

are not equivalent:

[image]

One correctly assigns `front` and `back` to two linked lists, one doesn't, which leads to segmentation fault.

Answer (score 9):

> as both set of statements are equivalent to each other

They absolutely aren't.

1. `*frontRef = source` means *dereference* `frontRef` and invoke `operator=` on the returned *lvalue* expression of type `node`.
2. `frontRef = &source` means *take the address of* `source` and *assign* it to `frontRef`.

If `frontRef` is uninitialized or null, (1) is undefined behavior, but (2) is fine.

Comment: but the fault occured in case of (2).

Answer (score 3):

1. `*frontRef = source; *backRef = f;`
2. `frontRef = &source; backRef = &f;`

These aren't equivalent.

Second one just updates local variable `frontRef` with another local variable `source`'s address, so it actually does not affect anything for the the caller side. You probably meant `frontRef` to be an out argument but it is not updated at all. (And same for `backRef`.)